# Error in using aws-java-sdk-s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to s3 sdk with very basic test and getting below error.

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIGNING_REGION
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:4227)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:4203)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:929)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:936)

aws-java-sdk-s3

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
<version>1.11.288</version>
</dependency

    ClientConfiguration cf = new ClientConfiguration();
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("<id>","<secret>");
    AmazonS3 amazonS3Client= 
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
    List<Bucket> buckets = amazonS3Client.listBuckets();
```

Maven dependency tree:

```
O] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ AwsSdkDemo ---
O] com.example:AwsSdkDemo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
O] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
O] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
O] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
O] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
O] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
O] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
O] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.27:compile
O] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.27:compile
O] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
O] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
O] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
O] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
O] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
O] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
O] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
O] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
O] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
O] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
O] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
O] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
O] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:compile
O] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.27:compile
O] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.27:compile
O] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.27:compile
O] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.27:compile
O] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
O] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
O] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
O] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
O] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
O] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
O] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.288:compile
O] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.125:compile
O] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.125:compile
O] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
O] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile
O] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile
O] |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
O] |  |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
O] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.10:compile
O] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
O] |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.125:compile
O] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.196:runtime
O] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.20:compile
O] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:test
O]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:test
O]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.10.RELEASE:test
O]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
O]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
O]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
O]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
O]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
O]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
O]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
O]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
O]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
O]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
O]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
O]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
O]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
O]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:test
O] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>AwsSdkDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AwsSdkDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.288</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.288</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you have an older version of the `aws-java-sdk-core` JAR. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and verify that all AWS JARs have the same version. Update your question with the output if you need more explanation.

Comment: thanks, I updated with mvn dependnency tree. It uses com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.125

Comment: That is actually very strange: `aws-sdk-java-s3` appears to be pulling in dependencies from earlier releases of the SDK. I took a quick look at the [POM](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.11.288/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.288.pom) and this shouldn't be happening: it should be referencing other modules with the same version.

Comment: This leads me to two questions: first, do you have a `<dependencyManagement>` in your project POM that would set the SDK version? Or do you define the property `awsjavasdk.version`?

Comment: ya, I have updated question with pom too. I just added new core version (1.11.288)  and now its working.

Comment: probably spring boot messing it up ?

Comment: Yep. There's a chain of dependency management declarations that end up [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-aws-dependencies/1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-aws-dependencies-1.2.2.RELEASE.pom), which limits AWS versions to 1.11.125. I would recommend not fighting this, but instead take out the `<version>` specification for the AWS JARs that you reference in your POM.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you everyone, issue was with having not consistent version of aws-core dependency that is pulled by spring. After manually giving core version (1.11.288) it resolves issue. As mentioned if we just not put version explicitly in pom in spring boot, it can also resolve this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar issue `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager:jar:1.11.430` is bringing in `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.125` to resolve this by specifically including the core-sdk jar in the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.430</version>
</dependency>
```

I also opened an issue against the aws-java-sdk: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1787

Comment: Work for me, but i use the latest one

Answer (score 1):

Though it is an old post, I am posting a solution. Hope it helps.

Follow below steps (you can skip remaining steps at any point if the problem is solved):

> 1. Make sure that `sdk-core` version and client version is same. If not then version of `sdk-core` must be higher than client library
> 2. In order to have same version for both `sdk-core` and client add ->

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.308</version> <-- Add recent version
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>   <-- don't remove
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

> 3. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and check where is the mismatch.
> 4. Add this line to capture the reference `System.out.println(HandlerContextKey.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());`
> 5. At the end clear your dependency cache. If you are using any IDE then invalidate that cache too

After adding the code mentioned at step 4 worked for me. `sdk-core` dependency was getting added by other dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good not to give 'aws-java-sdk-core' version manually, let spring it self decide for you and your applications with Spring boot2.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue,and I have resolved this issue by upgrading the
aws-java-sdk-s3 version as 1.12.334
aws.java.sdk.core.version as 1.11.1032

Always make sure you are in the latest and safest dependency version.